# Regex to find out specific part of an html page

Tags: php, regex

i want a regex to find out the below lines from a set of codes.
The part that i want to find:---

-->Copy frame link\",\"url240\":\"http:\/\/cs534515v4.vk.me\/u163220668\/videos\/1c1b06aec9.240.mp4\",\"url360\":\"http:\/\/cs534515v4.vk.me\/u163220668\/videos\/1c1b06aec9.360.mp4\",\"jpg\"<--

This code form part if an html page and i want to retrieve only the part shown.I am writing the codes in php

My complete codes.....

```
<?php

set_time_limit(0);
function get_content_of_url($url){
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
    $content = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $content;
}

$plyst  =   get_content_of_url("http://vk.com/video56612186_167113956");
preg_match('/link\\".*"jpg\\"/', $plyst , $matches);        


var_dump($matches);
//preg_match('/http:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\\/-_.]+/', $matches[0][0], $id);
//start_script($id[0]);

?>
```

Comment: What is the `-->Copy frame` part?  Is it part of the string you want to match?

Comment: this is part of the long string that i have to match.........................video_get_current_url\":\"Copy frame link\",\"url240\":\"http:\\\/\\\/cs534515v4.vk.me\\\/u163220668\\\/videos\\\/1c1b06aec9.240.mp4\",\"url360\":\"http:\\\/\\\/cs534515v4.vk.me\\\/u163220668\\\/videos\\\/1c1b06aec9.360.mp4\",\"jpg\":\"http:\\\/\\\/cs534515.vk.me\\\/u163220668\\\/video\\\/l_8a5b0712.jpg\",\"ip_subm\":1,\"nol........nomarlly what i wanted to do is only the get contents from copy frame link till the jpg

Comment: what i wanted is to get a reference to the links of the videos directly and i've found that its between the codes i've pasted i.e between link frame and jpg

Comment: I edited my answer to show how you would get the links of the videos..  Is that what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

How about this.

```
$str = "video_get_current_url\":\"Copy frame link\",\"url240\":\"http:\\\/\\\/cs534515v4.vk.me\\\/u163220668\\\/videos\\\/1c1b06aec9.24‌​0.mp4\",\"url360\":\"http:\\\/\\\/cs534515v4.vk.me\\\/u163220668\\\/videos\\\/1c1b06aec9.36‌​0.mp4\",\"jpg\":\"http:\\\/\\\/cs534515.vk.me\\\/u163220668\\\/video\\\/l_8a5b0712.jpg\",\"‌​ip_subm\":1,\"nologo";

preg_match('/\\"Copy\sframe.*"jpg\\"/is', $str, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

Output:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(199) ""Copy frame link","url240":"http:\\/\\/cs534515v4.vk.me\\/u163220668\\/videos\\/1c1b06aec9.24‌​0.mp4","url360":"http:\\/\\/cs534515v4.vk.me\\/u163220668\\/videos\\/1c1b06aec9.36‌​0.mp4","jpg""
}
```

**Edit:**

And then, if you wanted to extract the video url's from that:

```
preg_match_all('/(https?:.*?\.mp4)/', $matches[0], $id);

//Then echo out the url's
foreach ($id[0] as $url) {
    // the preg_replace strips out the double backslashes.
    echo preg_replace('/\\\\/', '', $url)."<br />";
}
```

Output:

```
http://cs534515v4.vk.me/u163220668/videos/1c1b06aec9.24‌​0.mp4

http://cs534515v4.vk.me/u163220668/videos/1c1b06aec9.36‌​0.mp4
```

Working example: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/329106d990fe8927a7670b9448770643afbd0865